# How to find and replace part of selected text in Sublime2 with only keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For example:

Original:

```
function[0] = abc0
```

Final:

```
function[1] = abc1
```

I am using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it works the same way - you open up the replace panel with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>, use tab to navigate the original and replacement input things, and select replace next or replace all. There's a *really* nice (unofficial?) set of docs here that I [referenced](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace.html) for this answer.